# Folders not found after mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following project structure:

[image: Project structure with views]

There is a folder called 'views' containing all my HTML files.

The problem now is, that my url looks like this: http://example.com/views/index, http://example.com/views/account,...

How do I use `mod_rewrite` in my `.htaccess` to get rid of the `views` part in the URL?

I just want that when someone visits http://example.com, it actually sees the file http://example.com/views/index.php.

I've got very close with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1
```

But the problem is that now all my other folders are not found anymore. My CSS from the folder `css` ain't found, also my `media` files are not found, and also not my PHP.

**Edit:**
This is my new `.htaccess`:

```
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php

RewriteRule ^(css|js|media|partials|php)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1
```

It gets very close. On the third line from the bottom I was able to exclude all folders for the rewrite_rule, resulting in media, css, js,... loading. But the problem is that that line, also removes the rewrite_rule above.

In the folder `php` there are files like `example.php`, `test.php`,... But I refer to it without extension. But that's not working anymore because the third rule from the bottom ignores ALL rewrite_rules; so also the rules removing the PHP-extension.

So how do I exclude folders for only a specific rewrite_rule?

**Edit2:**
Solved.

Correct `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views|css|js|media|partials|php)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rule adds prefix `/views` to all URLs, including those starting with `/css`, `/js`, `/media` and so on. You need to exclude those.

Comment: How would I exclude those?

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.